# How to resolve "Referenced error: Highcharts not defined" when using Easychart?

Tags: 7, charts

I installed the [Easychart](https://www.drupal.org/project/easychart) module 7.x-3.7 in my Drupal 7.51 site. Using Highcharts 4.2.7 in libraries 7.x-2.3. I extracted highcharts and easychart-master contents into `all/libraries/highcharts` and `all/libraries/easychart` folders respectively. Easychart_ex and Chart contenttypes are shown when adding content.

However in my browser console I am getting this error:

> Referenced error: Highcharts not defined.

I tried all the suggestions mentioned in the ***Notes*** at the end of the answer to "[How to plot a chart from CSV uploaded in a content type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228892/how-to-plot-a-graph-chart-from-csv-uploaded-in-a-content-type/228909#228909)", but none of them helped.

Is there any Easychart latest module I am missing or is it the way it is supposed to work (only with Highcharts 4.2.7) is a question left to Drupal!

Comment: Please note the edits I applied to your question, mostly trying to improve the formatting/readability of it, and adding a link to the module's project page (always recommended for any contributed module). Feel free to further improve if needed. Or if you don't like my edit at all, just use the "rollback" link (within revisions, which you can find in that "edited" link right above this comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Easychart](https://www.drupal.org/project/easychart) 7.x-3.7 ***recommends*** version 4.2.7 of the Highcharts library. This is also what you can see in [this specific commit](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/easychart/commit/?id=ca69d934c74b9e744f3861a91526b4ccc1a91378).

And the [Easychart](https://www.drupal.org/project/easychart) project page states "***... v4.x of the Highcharts library***".

So it appears that using Highcharts 5.0.3 is not yet supported, which probably also explains the folder problems you described in your own answer. I don't think that you're missing anything else (or some other "latest" module) that you're missing (as long as you stick to the recommended version of Highcharts you should be fine).

PS: Be aware that there is also the feature request about "[make use of new Highcharts 5.0.0 methods](https://github.com/daemth/easychart/issues/56)" (for the Easychart plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I found that Easychart expects file path for highcharts as js/highcharts and recommended version is "highcharts 4.2.7". In highcharts 5.0.3, the folder structure got changed to code/js/highcharts.js. If file path is changed easychart.module (all/modules/easychart) from js/highcharts to code/js/highcharts, there will be subsequent problems in ec.min.js (Highcharts.getoptions.color2 undefined)-meaning entire folder structure is not correct. When I replaced with the recommended version of highcharts4.2.7, easychart appeared without any problem.